# How to install preexisting html, css and dreamweaver files into dreamweaver cs6?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am completely new to web design but I have to change out my organization's old website for a new one. I need to install the site into dreamweaver so I can start making changes to the text and the images and fix links that don't work. I was basically handed a set of html, css and dreamweaver files with no instruction. How do I put the files into dreamweaver and define the site or whatever, and how do I publish the site once its polished, and do I need to put in on a server or something? This is my first time doing anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to `site > manage sites` in the menu. This will allow you to setup parameters for the server and the local environment. If you have an exported Dreamweaver site file this is where you would `import site` to adjust the configuration.